Trying to use Divergence Theorem to Calculate Heat Flux of a Cylinder
Long time lurker, first time poster here.  I'm new to using mathjax, so please bear with me!  Given Problem in Picture Form
I'm trying to solve a problem for a school project, in which we calculate the heat flux through four different shapes.  The one I'm stumped on currently is the cylinder with dimensions $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $1 \le z \le 4$, with the temperature at any point given by $T (x, y, z) = (x^2 + y^2) z$ and a thermal conductivity of $55$.
I'm trying to use Divergence Theorem to just calculate the triple integral instead of calculating and summing each of the three surfaces (bottom, top, and curved side surface), but I'm running into a problem for my final solution.
Using Divergence Theorem, I have the triple integral set as below:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{1}^{4} -220 z r dz dr d\theta $$
Solving the above gives me an answer of $-1650 \pi$, but the correct answer is actually $-110 \pi$.  If I were to change the bounds of $z$ to $0 \le z \le 1$ instead of $1 \le z \le 4$ I get the right heat flux, and indeed from an example given by Surface Integral of a Vector Field shows them changing the bounds.  I just don't quite understand why we need to do this, and if Divergence Theorem really isn't the way to go about this problem.
Thanks for any help/criticism!
Edit (06/20/24):
Just an update, I emailed my professor if it would be possible for them to calculate the answer themselves to see what the discrepancy was and the conclusion was the answer sheet did indeed have an error. The correct answer is $-1650\pi$.
Thank you to everyone who helped me with this problem, I learned a great deal from this!

Let’s start with basics. How do we get the heat flux from $T$ and the thermal conductivity? Also, your cylinder does not include the top and bottom disks, does it? So think carefully about the divergence theorem.

Thermal conductivity (k = 55) was given, and using $$ q = -k \Delta T $$ (where q is the heat flux):
$$q = -55\langle 2xz, 2yz, x^2+y^2 \rangle$$
Calculating the divergence:
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{q} = -220z$$
My idea was that since Divergence Theorem is valid for 3d solids, the projection of the cylinder onto the xy plane would be the integral of:
$$\iint_{0 \leq r \leq 1 \atop 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi} r , dr , d\theta$$
Since these are the "tops and bottoms" of the cylinder, we could then just integrate these results across the z axis bound by $$1 \leq z \leq 4$$.

OK, you should include those details by editing your original post. But the projection of the surface they gave you is just the circle $x^2+y^2=1$, not the disk. I believe the surface of the cylinder is just that, and the upper and lower disks are not included. So how do you apply the divergence theorem?

@TedShifrin Incidentally for this problem, it doesn't matter whether or not you choose to include the disks. The heat into the top disk is equal to the heat out of the bottom disk.

Divergence Theorem is given by:
$$ \iiint_V (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{q}) , dV $$
With bounds $$ \iiint_V (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{T}) , dV = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_1^4 (\nabla \cdot \mathbf{T}) , r , dz , dr , d\theta $$ I get the triple integral of
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{1}^{4} -220 z r dz dr d\theta $$
I then just solved the triple integral and got $$-1650pi$$, I can also write out those steps if need be.
I thought that maybe since a disk is a region bound by a circle, I could use that to set up the r and theta components of the triple integral.

You are right about the two disks. Your triple integral is set up correctly.

Then I guess I'm at a loss on how to procede.  Am I just calculating the triple integral wrong (since the set up is correct), or am I missing something?

I have not done the arithmetic, but their answer is just wrong. This happens.

I've checked your arithmetic, and you're correct. BTW, in your original equation, you should have $q=k\nabla T$. The Laplacian comes later. $\nabla\cdot q = \nabla\cdot (\nabla T) = \nabla^2 T$ or, in typical more advanced math notation, $\Delta $T.

I've included in my original post an image of the question from the pdf itself, because maybe I'm misinterpretating something?
Otherwise I'm just very confused as to why my results are incorrect, when both the professor and the second image I linked in my post to a calc 3 resource both say I'm wrong.
Thanks for your help throughout this!

Your answer is correct. Either the question was not copied here correctly, or the "correct answer" is not so.
First, we compute the heat. We have
$$\vec{q} = -k \nabla T = -k \langle 2 x z, 2 y z, x^2 + y^2 \rangle$$
If we choose to work in the (more natural) cylindrical coordinate system, we have
$$\vec{q} = -k \langle 2 r z \cos \theta, 2 r z \sin \theta, r^2 \rangle$$
Now we compute flux through the flat surfaces. Those surfaces can be parameterized by $r \times \theta \in [0, 1] \times [0, 2 \pi]$. The top surface has surface normal $\hat{n} dS = \langle 0, 0, 1 \rangle r dr d\theta$ (the bottom has the same, just negated). The flux through the top is therefore
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 -k r^2 (r dr d\theta) = -2 \pi k \int_0^1 r^3 dr = -\frac{\pi}{2} k$$
(the bottom has the same, just positive - heat is leaving from the bottom). Since the flux for the two disks have equal magnitude but different signs, the net flux through those two surfaces is zero.
We can parameterize the curved surface by $\theta \times z \in [0, 2 \pi] \times [1, 4]$. The surface normal is $\hat{n} dS = \langle \cos \theta, \sin \theta, 0 \rangle d \theta dz$ (keeping in mind the radius for each point on the surface is $1$). The flux through this surface is therefore
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_1^4 -k (2 z) dz d\theta = -4 \pi k \int_1^4 z dz = -30 \pi k$$
The net flux through the cylinder (all surfaces included) is therefore just $-30 \pi k$. This is precisely what you obtained using the divergence theorem.

I've edited my original post to include an image of the pdf pertaining to the question itself.
I went to my professor before coming here and had asked for help, but all they did was say the answer was wrong and didn't elaborate further.
The second image I have linked in my original post also shows the surface integral method of solving it, and they get -110pi as an answer.
I feel very confused atm.
Also, thanks for the edit of my original post to clean up the formatting!

@SayNoToDecaf So indeed, the question was copied correctly. The answer you linked does not make sense. The variable $v$ should range from $1$ to $4$, not $0$ to $1$. It is even more interesting because the correct limits make an appearance in the second line, but then disappear. I strongly believe there is something wrong with the answer (perhaps the original problem was written for a cylinder with $z \in [0, 1]$, but a different version of it was created for $z \in [1, 4]$ but the answer not accordingly updated). Your answer is definitely correct.

Just an update, I emailed my professor if it would be possible for them to calculate the answer themselves to see what the discrepancy was and the conclusion was the answer sheet did indeed have an error.
I've updated the original question to reflect this for future viewers, and thanks for the assistance!
